# Segmentation fault in DCOracle2 Oracle Database Bindings for Python

Tags: python, oracle

Currently we are using [DCORacle2](http://old.zope.org/Members/matt/dco2/) Oracle binding for Python.

DCOracle2 is no more maintained but we are using it because of legacy constraints.
Whenever I try to create 'SQLT_CLOB' with any higher data size it crashes (segmentation fault).

With this Python code segmentation fault can be reproduced:

```
from DCOracle2 import DCOracle2,dbi

connection = DCOracle2.connect(user='username', password='password',database='DBname')
lob_locator = connection.LobLocator('SQLT_CLOB')
data = '1' * 90000
lob_locator.write(data)
connection.procedures.your_schema_name.your_procedure_name(lob_locator) # This line causes segmentation fault
connection.close()
```

This is the simple procedure I have created:

```
create or replace function proceclob(i_clob clob) return clob as
l_tmp clob;
begin
  l_tmp := i_clob;
  return l_tmp;
end;
```

This is the traceback that I can see after segfault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff69f5d80 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff69f5d80 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000462e51 in PyString_FromStringAndSize ()
#2  0x00007ffff5da612f in listDescriptors (self=0x7ffff7e898f0, parmh=0x7ffff00ec768, entry=0x7ffff5fb0fa0, current=<optimized out>) at src/dco2.c:2293
#3  0x00007ffff5da69ea in ServerContext_describe (self=0x7ffff7e898f0, args=<optimized out>) at src/dco2.c:2425
#4  0x000000000056d4a4 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#5  0x000000000056dc92 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#6  0x000000000056dc92 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#7  0x00000000005747c0 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#8  0x00000000005697b0 in ?? ()
#9  0x000000000043a8b6 in PyObject_Call ()
#10 0x000000000043b626 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#11 0x00000000004fdc2a in ?? ()
#12 0x000000000056d54e in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#13 0x00000000005747c0 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#14 0x0000000000569ee1 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#15 0x000000000056a6b3 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#16 0x000000000056ba75 in Py_Main ()
#17 0x00007ffff68cd76d in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#18 0x000000000041bb11 in _start ()
```

PS: This code works perfectly with Python 2.6 but crashes for Python 2.7 and above versions.

I have tried debugging python with GDB but could not find any specific reason. DCOracle2 version we are using is 1.3 (Latest)

Please provide any hints if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue.
The issue was:
Oracle headers define typedef 'ub4' as 'unsigned int' on some platforms and 'unsigned long int' on some platforms.
On my platform it was defining 'ub4' as 'unsigned int' which was causing 'Out of bounds' exception for pointer pointing larger data chunk.